# Egg used for breaded poultry added to other parts of the dish. Is this a health hazard?

Tags: eggs, poultry

I often make breaded poultry (chicken, turkey) or pork. To do that, I dump the cut in a bowl of scrambled egg then coat it with flour/breading etc in another plate. The recipe after that varies but thats not important.

I sometimes think tossing the rest of the egg is a waste, so if I'm also cooking rice I put the rest of the egg on the rice in the rice cooker and let it there until im done cooking. This is either during the final stages of the rice cooking or when its done and the cooker keeps it warm. Do you think the heat there is enough to remove whatever possible salmonella contamination from the moment the poultry came in contact with the scrambled egg?

Comment: I have always leaned on the side of caution and simply cooked the egg up and gave it to my dog. He loves the treat.

Comment: important cover-my-ass clarification i have only done this when I'm the only one eating it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as the egg is cooked to the doneness necessary to safely cook the pork, this is a fine process.

Someone will surely say that if the egg sits out it will be unsafe. In fact, you have a window of several hours, especially if it was cold to start.

The scenario of putting the egg in while the rice is in the 'Hold' phase DOES sound a little risky, though, as that stage probably does not go above 140 F

If adding to the rice do it with several minutes of full heat still to come, or scramble the egg in the frying pan and add it like that.